# Can I make Flash CS4's 3D functionality work with 3D glasses?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, papervision3d

I know it can be done in papevision -> http://codejockeyscorner.blogspot.com/2009/04/papervision3d-anaglyph-scene.html but I'd like to be able to do it just using Flash's 3D functionality. I'm aware that its more 2.5D but was wondering if anybody knew how to create a situation so you can view it with 3D glasses (red and blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stereoscopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image) images can be made with [a simple camera](http://www.qpcc.org.uk/?page_id=835) so the choice of a 3d engine shouldn't make a difference : )

Very basically : you have to do is to duplicate the scene (one blue/ onered) and change slightly the [PerspectiveProjection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html) for each. The viewpoints need to be placed at a distance proportional to the one you have between your two eyes.